# In org mode, how do I reference a figure?

Tags: org-mode, pandoc

I have a figure declared like this:

```
#+CAPTION: Google NGrams Viewer Search
#+NAME: fig:ngrams
[[file:ngrams.png]]
```

And I'd like to reference it, so that I can write, e.g. `Please refer to Figure [[some magic thing here]]` and have it output `Please refer to Figure 1`. I'm using pandoc to convert from .org to .pdf.

I've been trying writing `[[fig:ngrams]]`, as in `Please refer to Figure [[fig:ngrams]]`, but neither Pandoc nor pandoc-citeproc seem to understand that kind of link, and they transform it to `Please refer to Figure fig:ngrams`.

Comment: In Org, one refers to a figure like you suggested, e.g. `Figure [[fig:ngrams]]`.  This *works* with `ox.el`, e.g. `ox-latex.el`.  If you must use `pandoc` instead of `ox-latex.el` for your PDFs needs, perhaps the right approach would be to file a bug to the Pandoc org-parser maintainers to let them know that it does not support the links syntax fully.

Comment: Your question has a lot of traffic, and the up to date answer is the one with the least votes (from @kostas-tsiligkiris). Could you consider accepting his answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is another way to reference figures, by using `#+NAME:` before the figure. For example:

```
#+CAPTION: Example of the process
#+NAME: fig:theprocess
[[./Images/process.png]]
```

And later in the place where you need the reference, you add an internal link:

```
And as can be seen in figure [[fig:theprocess]], the process...
```

This works nicely with latex export.

Comment: Are there any keyboard shortcuts that support insertion of such links in a large document (like how reftex behaves with latex documents) ?

Answer (score 11):

Figured it out myself. Turns out with the latest pandoc and pandoc-crossref you can do this:

```
#+CAPTION: Google NGrams Viewer Searches
#+LABEL: fig:ngrams
[[file:ngrams.png]]
```

Then:

`Please refer to [cite:@fig:ngrams].`

Comment: No longer working in my installation `: Emacs version: GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20)
:  of 2020-08-25
: org version: 9.3.7`

Answer (score 9):

You can also use org-ref. Then you can use ref:ngrams to reference a figure. This works well with LaTeX export. It probably works with pandoc too.

Comment: Note that after org version 8.3 this needs `(setq org-latex-prefer-user-labels t)` to work: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38457/name-is-ignored-unless-running-emacs-with-q