# `#+NAME:` is ignored unless running Emacs with `-q`

Tags: org-export, init-file

I am trying to export an `.org` buffer with the following contents:

```
#+CAPTION: My subgraph.
#+NAME: fig:subgraph
[[/tmp/image-4383FmT.png]]
```

The following `latex` output is produced:

```
% Created 2018-01-30 Tue 09:32
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{meir}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={meir},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 24.5.1 (Org mode 9.1.4)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{/tmp/image-4383FmT.png}
\caption{\label{fig:org39390dd}
My subgraph.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `#+NAME:` command was ignored. It works properly when I start Emacs with `emacs -q`. In the search for the guilty line in my configuration, I commented out lines in `init.el` until nothing remained, but the problem persists. What is going on? What is the difference between `-q` and empty init file? (I compared the `*Messages*` buffer after starting `Emacs` both ways and did not find any difference)

Comment: Try again with `emacs -Q` this also doesn't run the system configuration files for `emacs`.

Comment: It works with either `emacs -q` or `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bit of differences between `emacs -q` and emacs with no `init.el`.  See "[Summary: Sequence of Actions at Startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html)".

Do you happen to have Emacs 25.2.2 with Org mode 8.2.10?  Because that's what I have on my Debian System.  When you run `emacs -q`, do you run that older version of org mode?  Post the good output if you don't know what you are running.

Org version 8.3 or later introduced `org-latex-prefer-user-labels`, which is `nil` as a default.  With this variable set to non-`nil`, you can use your custom ID, which is taken from `#+NAME`.

`C-h v org-latex-prefer-user-labels` to see more detail.

Here is the one I got from Org 8.2.10:

```latex
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{/tmp/image-4383FmT.png}
\caption{\label{fig:subgraph}My subgraph.}
\end{figure}
% Emacs 25.2.2 (Org mode 8.2.10)
```

And with default Org 9.1.6:

```latex
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{/tmp/image-4383FmT.png}
\caption{\label{fig:org15c1279}
My subgraph.}
\end{figure}
```

And this is Org 9.1.6 with `org-latex-prefer-user-labels` set to `t`:

```latex
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{/tmp/image-4383FmT.png}
\caption{\label{fig:subgraph}
My subgraph.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The output that I posted indicates: `Emacs 24.5.1 (Org mode 9.1.4)`. When Emacs starts, there is no variable `org-latex-prefer-user-labels`. It appears only after an export. Nonetheless, setting it to `t` resolves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning , you said `emacs -q` _works_.  What is the version of your `emacs -q`?  Plus, please fix the question title, it's not about `-q` or `init.el`.

Comment: `emacs -q --version` gives `GNU Emacs 24.5.1`. Now that I am thinking about it: why does it work with `-q`?

Comment: And Org's veresion is?

Comment: With `-q`, `org-version` gives `8.2.10`. I guess this explains it!

Comment: Thanks, this works. Any idea why they added this variable and set it to `nil` by default? Seems to only add inconvenience to the users...